# How to make a protection of many times pressing the button?

Tags: java, android

In my app I use a camera, and I want to take a pictures. In my app is button (Photo). If I press it one times - all work perfect, but if I press button many times until camera take picture, my app hangs. How can I fix it?

Comment: How about disabling the button on initial press?  button1.setEnabled(false);

Comment: You can also feedback the user and change the button text accordingly ("Taking photo") while it is disabled.

Answer (score 6):

In your onClickListener call [Button.setEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) and set it to false.

Then set it to true when you've finished taking the photo.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a listener that disables the button on press (`setEnalbed(false)`), than start a countdown thread that re-enables it after some time, 200ms maybe, or whatever fits the best.

After second thoughts this might not be a really good idea.
There is a chance that the thread will not be scheduled to run, so if you exactly know the point when you can re-enable the button in your code, don't use threads.

Comment: Indeed one would likely need to reEnable the button when safe to use again